# How do I find the cause of an unknown beep?

Tags: electrical

Something in our house is beeping every 40-45 seconds, and sounds like a smoke detector needing a battery change.

We’ve removed all batteries from all smoke detectors simultaneously and the beeps persists.

We’ve checked the CO2 monitor.

The beep is coming from the basement, and sounds like it’s coming from near the location of the furnace and water heater.

The beep DOES stop when flipping breakers. However, switching them all off right away or too quickly has no effect. It appears that you need to switch them off roughly in conjunction with the beep itself, and it only requires turning off the breakers on the right side of our box. I don’t have a list of what each fuse is connected to off the top of my head, but the fact it only stops after turning off a specific half of the box seems notable. And it has to be ALL the breakers on that side.

After eliminating the beep, it’s been returning every 24-36 hours, and we go through the process again.

---

Over the last few days, the speed at which it returns is increasing, jumping from 24-36 hours to as quickly as 2-4 hours. Additionally, the number of breakers required to shut off has increased, and it now seems to need all the breakers on the right side shut off along with 4-5/6ths of the breakers on the left of the panel to be shut off.

---

We’re at a complete loss. How do we track this down?

Comment: Disconnect all the devices on those circuits and power them up individually.

Comment: Are your smoke/CO detectors hardwired? If they were, pulling the batteries might cause this behavior.

Comment: It seems half an hour or less devoted to finding the beep should do the trick. Particularly if you have a general idea already. Sure, a bunch of standing around waiting for the next beep, but better than days being bothered by it. On the off chance - is there a water leak detector on the floor near/behind the water heater?

Comment: Battery backup for phone company fiber (e.g., Verizon FIOS) or similar?

Comment: I once had an issue like that and it wound up being my heated mattress cover.  (Yes, I had to reboot my bed.)

Comment: Septic tank alarm?

Comment: @JonCuster Believe me, we've spent more than a half hour. We're pretty confident we know the general location it's coming from, but cannot find anything in that area that seems to be the cause. While really trying to track it today, it seemed rather strongly to be coming from an area in/around the ducts coming off the furnace. We looked around from every angle we could--and there are quite a few that were obstructed by the ductwork--and could not spot anything other than the wood and spiderwebs.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact We've got high-speed ethernet (Spectrum/Comcast) but not fiber. I only mention in case that could still be applicable and I'm just unaware.

Comment: Not just fiber. It is a little more common, in my experience. with fiber than with other cable types because if you have phone service that used to be copper and is now part of a fiber connection then the phone service won't work unless the optical network terminal has power.

Answer (score 5):

So, I can't guarantee that this is the solution, but it sounds exactly like a water detector in the basement at my grandmother's house that drove us absolutely crazy for around 6 months.

At her house, the Water heater pan had the detector setup on the back side, so we couldn't see it at all from the access point.

The unit was powered wirelessly by three induction coils that were attached to the house's Romex cabling.  It also had a 9-volt battery as a backup, which is what caused her beeping.  Take note that the unit at her house was installed in the late 1970s, so this isn't new technology. Below is a quick and dirty recreation of what it looked like:

[image: 1970s moisture detector]

At grandma's house, we also had the issue where we had to flip multiple breakers to disable the beep.  Which is what made me think that you may have a similar unit producing the beep.

We eventually found the unit because one of the induction coils was clamped around the power cable going to the water heater, which was the only visible indicator from the access door.  So, take a look at the power cables around the area and see if there are any clamps with two small wires coming off of them.  The chance of this being the solution is low, but it's also a relatively easy check.

Comment: **This** is pretty much the only way it can be powered from multiple breakers.  Sherlock Holmes had something to say about situations like this.